# How can I reduce number of handshakes to a redis client?

Tags: lua, redis, in-memory-database, jedis

I am writing an application which requires a very fast response time, I have some queries to redis which would require intersection and union of multiple sets . 

An example would be 

**((A union B) intersection C)**


However when I do it with java client, each query requires 1 more handshake thus increasing my response time.

I was wondering if there was a way that I could do it in a single handshake, Lua scripting looks like a good option but I'm not sure how it would work internally

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [pipeline](http://redis.io/topics/pipelining) to reduce the RTT.

With `pipeline`, you can send multiple commands to Redis at one time, and read all replies latter.

Answer (score 1):

- Redis lua script is a blocking method which does everything at once
  inside the redis server.
- so you will avoid network round trip for
  sure which you needed.
- Since it is blocking you should always be
  aware of when to use it, if all those union and intersection takes a
  5 sec in production environment then it is blocking for other
  commands that are waiting to be executed. other commands may not get executed and comes out throwing an time out error which may cause things worse.
- So alternately you can do
  partial lua script calls for every 50 elements are so (derive an
  optimal number by trying out with different numbers).
- Also consider using sunion and sinter of multiple elements instead of using only 2 if it fits. 
  ie,

> sunion set1 set2 set3... 
>   instead of
>
> sunionstore temp set1 set2
>
> sunionstore temp temp set3 and so on.

Hope this helps.